# Self-ajointness of the Laplacian over a Riemannian manifold with boundary

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces, laplacian

I have some doubts about on a passage found on this article (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.08136.pdf).

Let

1. $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with boundary;
2. $E\to M$ be an hermitian fiber bundle;
3. $\Delta$ be a Laplace-Beltrami operator defined from a connection over $E$ compatible with the fiber metric;
4. $\Gamma(E)$ be the space of smooth sections of $E$;
5. $H^s(E)$ be the $s$-sobolev space over $E$.

If $\psi_1,\psi_2\in \Gamma(E)$ I can compute $\langle \Delta \psi_1,\psi_2\rangle-\langle \psi_1,\Delta\psi_2\rangle$ integrating by parts and I get
$$
\langle \Delta \psi_1,\psi_2\rangle-\langle \psi_1,\Delta\psi_2\rangle=\int_{\partial M} [(\dot\varphi_1, \varphi_2)-(\varphi_1,\dot\varphi_2)]\,\mathrm d\sigma
$$
where $\varphi_a=\psi_a|_{\partial M}$ and $\dot \varphi_a$ is the outer normal derivative along $\partial M$.

The article says that this formula is valid even if $\psi_1,\psi_2\in H^2(E)$. In this case $(\varphi_a,\dot \varphi_a)$ is defined as the image of $\psi_a$ under the map $b\colon H^2(E)\to H^{3/2}(\partial E)\oplus H^{1/2}(\partial E)$, which is the unique continuous extension of the boundary map $\psi\in \Gamma(E)\mapsto (\varphi,\dot \varphi)\in \Gamma(\partial E)\oplus \Gamma(\partial E)$ (that's the Lions-Magenes theorem).

I don't get how to obtain this formula when $\psi_1,\psi_2\in H^2(E)$.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you happy with the statement in $\mathbb R^d$ and you don't see why it still works on a manifold, or the flat case also worries you?

Comment: I'm happy only with the smooth case. Even if $M=\mathbb R^d$ and the metric is flat, I have problem integrating by parts with sobolev function (I'm a beginner with sobolev space)

Comment: So the way to do it is to use density, with a smooth approximating sequence, and notice that the convergence is strong e.g. in L^2 of the boundary.

Comment: I know that $H^2(E)$ is the closure of $\Gamma(E)$ with respect to the sobolev norm $||u||=\sqrt{||u||_2+||\Delta u||_2}$. Do you reccomend this approximation?

Comment: Take a sequence in $\Gamma(E)^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\psi_{i}^{n}\to\psi_{i}$,
$i=1,2$ in $H^{2}$. By continuity of the trace we also have $\varphi_{i}^{n}\to\varphi_{i}$
in $H^{3/2}$ and $\dot{\varphi_{i}}^{n}\to\dot{\varphi_{i}}$ in
$H^{1/2}.$
Then,

Comment: \begin{align*}
\left\langle \Delta\psi_{1},\psi_{2}\right\rangle -\left\langle \psi_{1},\Delta\psi_{2}\right\rangle  & =\left\langle \Delta\psi_{1}^{n},\psi_{2}^{n}\right\rangle -\left\langle \psi_{1}^{n},\Delta\psi_{2}^{n}\right\rangle +e_{1}^{n}\\
 & =\int_{\partial M}\left[\left(\dot{\varphi}_{1}^{n},\varphi_{2}^{n}\right)-\left(\varphi_{1}^{n},\dot{\varphi}_{2}^{n}\right)\right]\,\mathrm{d}\sigma+e_{1}^{n}\\
 & =\int_{\partial M}\left[\left(\dot{\varphi}_{1},\varphi_{2}\right)-\left(\varphi_{1},\dot{\varphi}_{2}\right)\right]\,\mathrm{d}\sigma+e_{1}^{n}+e_{2}^{n}
\end{align*}

Comment: and $$
e_{1}\leq\left\Vert \psi_{1}^{n}-\psi_{1}\right\Vert \left\Vert \psi_{2}\right\Vert +\left\Vert \psi_{2}^{n}-\psi_{2}\right\Vert \left\Vert \psi_{1}\right\Vert +\left\Vert \psi_{1}^{n}-\psi_{1}\right\Vert \left\Vert \psi_{2}^{n}\right\Vert +\left\Vert \psi_{2}^{n}-\psi_{2}\right\Vert \left\Vert \psi_{1}^{n}\right\Vert \to0
$$
 and similarly for $e_{2}...$

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I see!